# AWS Cognito iOS: How to replace / upgrade from AWS MobileHubHelper generated code?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am developing an iOS application with user authentication via a AWS Cognito user pool (with email/password authentication).

The initial Xcode project and source code was generated by the AWS MobileHub code generator (that is no longer available).

It contained the `AWSMobileHubHelper` framework, an `AWSMobileClient`, and a few view controllers and storyboards related to authentication (like `SignInViewController`, `UserPoolForgotPasswordViewController` etc.)

(Since then, I moved to using the [Serverless](https://serverless.com) framework, so I no longer rely on the MobileHub "managing" my AWS resources - but the code structure of the Xcode project for the authentication parts is still the same.)

Now, it seems that MobileHubHelper is no longer maintained (the [Podfile](https://github.com/aws/aws-mobilehub-helper-ios/blob/master/Podfile) referencing older AWS SDK versions - although "deprecated" is not explicitly mentioned).

Also, the code generator has been removed from the MobileHub console.

Now, there are multiple "auth"-related repositories / SDKs, like

- AWSCognitoAuth
- AWSAuthCore
- AWSAuthUI
- AWSUserPoolsSignIn

I'm lost.

I want to be able to modify the UI, and keep the option to add Facebook or Google authentication at a later date.

The steps described in the [Cognito User Pools tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/tutorial-integrating-user-pools-ios.html) differs significantly from the ones in the ["Mobile App Development" tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/how-to-cognito-integrate-an-existing-identity-pool.html#how-to-auth-connect-to-your-backend) - and both don't really match the structure of my (generated) code.

The [CognitoYourUserPoolsSample](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/CognitoYourUserPools-Sample) and [CognitoAuthSample](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/CognitoAuth-Sample) are different again.

**What do I need to do to upgrade my authentication code and UI from the AWSMobileHubHelper-generated code  to the latest AWS SDKs?**

**Second issue: I used AWSUserFileManager from MobileHubHelper to upload user files - what do I use now?**